# Replace textures with colors in OBJ file?

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, color

How can you use Blender to replace textures with solid colors?

Take this model: https://poly.google.com/view/aAp0r0v9D-t.

The model has defined geometries for eyes, but uses texture to add color.

1) If we instead want to use solid colors for the eyes instead of using textures, how could you accomplish this?

2) What if we want to separate each eye, i.e., let each eye be a different color?

Comment: What you're asking for is fairly simple in Blender.  Removing the texture channel is also just a click away in the texture properties at right.  Placing different colors  for each eye where geometry (faces) exist can also be allotted different material slots with little effort.  Will get back to you on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Object mode, select the object you wish to change colours on and click on the little ball icon at right.
This opens up the object's material channels or 'slots'.

[image]

Each face on an object can have one material slot which can be shared by other faces in that same or even other objects. With your cursor in the 3D window and the object selected. (RMB)  you can then access it's material slot(s)

Get into Edit mode (press TAB) and select just one of the faces you wish to de-texture.

In the materials panel at right, open up the "Diffuse" tab  and scroll to the top to see the list of materials this object is using.

The one that belongs to the face you've selected should be highlited.

Go up to the icons at the top again and select what looks like a multicoloured square.  That's the texture panel that is attached to the currently selected material slot.

[image]

Open that and scroll up to the top.  You'll see a list of textures.  There can only be one texture attached to each material slot so the one concerned with the selected material should be highlited.

Underneath that list is a one line slot that dispays the same name as the highlited one above.

To it's right there's a big 'X' .   That's what you have to click on to delete this texture slot.  If there's more than one showing, they're stray entries anyway so you can delete any you see there.  It won't affect other material slots that may be using those.

Once that's gone you're back to the basic colour that's showing in the material slot.

You can change this by opening the materials again and opening the 'Diffuse' tab, clicking in the small coloured  window.  A colour wheel will present itself.  Choose the colour by dragging the tiny white dot around.  To exit, press ESC.

-===============-

To re-colour faces, select the object, then go to Edit mode, (press TAB) and then press ALT-TAB and selct "Faces".  This which will place you in the "Faces mode. (amazingly)

In the 3D window you will see the faces associated with that object, all with dots in them.  Right clicking on any of these will highlite them.  Hold Shift down to multiselect.

Once selected, press the Plus sign to the right of the uppermost list.  A new (blank) slot will appear up there.  Give it a name by clicking in the slot below with an X at it's immediate right.  It may well have the default name - "Material" already in there.

Once named, click the "Assign" button.  Those surfaces selected will all take on this new material slot.

So - you can have a different materials or colours for each face if you wish, or the same material can be shared by several faces.

-==========-

If you have queries about this particular answer just leave a comment here.
They will be emailed to me.

Additional Info -

Have come across a new question relating to your own...  The answer has an animated demo!

The link -

[Question on reflections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105202/question-on-reflections)

Comment: Thanks so much! For some models (e.g., https://poly.google.com/view/dXYoN00Ng8j), the eyes are not defined as separate geometries but rather drawn in the texture. Since the textures have UV mappings, is there a way to write a script to automate the creation of geometries that match UV mappings? In other words, could a script create geometries from the texture UV mappings of this elephant and create the eyes?

Comment: Added as a separate question so you can earn points :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105238/automate-geometry-creation-to-match-texture-uv-mappings :)

Comment: You're welcome  @Crashalot.  I wish I could draw like that. (elephant) Get those human expressions as well as artists do.  As for extracting the eyes, I'd have to agree with dave  on that one, not that I've been into Blender's scripting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The goal is to write a script and repeat the process for other models as well -- not just the elephant. How long do you think it would take to write a script like this?

Comment: Have no knowledge on scripting.  Not in Blender that is.  Best of luck with that.