# Reflections do not show in imported model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects

I'm making a Martian habitat animation for a school project and I imported one of the public NASA rovers into my workspace to use. One thing I have noticed is that the windows on the rover is black, yet on the videos where NASA showcases it, the ground reflects onto the window.

[image: My model.]

My model.
[image]
NASA's model.[image]

Here is what it looks like in edit mode.

Comment: You should add a screen capture about the materials used for the windows

Comment: The windows don't have separate materials that differ from the rest of the model. Here is the screen capture. https://gyazo.com/350436083744f8db9efa45a33f452161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model contains only one material. If you want the windows to have another one, go in the material panel and add it (see below). For this example I've set it red. I've done it using Blender Internal but for Cycles this is exactly the same principle (you'll simply need to setup the material with nodes).

[image]

Now you need to associate the wanted faces to this new material.
Enter edit mode, select the faces, choose the material and click "assign".

Here the windows are composed of four layers (probably for security reasons:). So to access the layer behind I hide the first one with <kbd>H</kbd>.

Once done, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to make hidden parts reappear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add several materials to a single object. In your case, I'd add a glossy black material, then select the window faces and apply the glossy black (I'd not use a glass material, as there's nothing inside the model, and transparency is slow to render).

The same applies to all parts of the model that should have a material (or surface texture) that differs from the main body (like the undercarriage, the wheels and details on the main body).

To add a new material to an object, click on the "+" button next to the list of materials, then select the new (empty) line and create a new material.
Then select the faces in your model to which you want to apply that new material, select the new material and click the "apply" button.

Comment: Whenever I try to just highlight the windows, the material ends up being on the whole model, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Do you add a new material, or replace the current one?