# Automate geometry creation to match texture UV mappings?

Tags: texturing, scripting, uv

In this model, https://poly.google.com/view/dXYoN00Ng8j), the eyes are not defined as separate geometries but rather drawn in the texture.

Since the texture has UV mappings, is there a way to write a script to automate the creation of geometries that match UV mappings?

1) In other words, could a script create geometries from the texture UV mappings of this elephant and create the eyes?

Answer (score 1):

In short yes, but It could take forever to do so too. It could be much faster and easier to remove mesh faces at the eyes in the model and attach a modified sphere with UV Map/s (Duplicated) to display your details but ultimately depends on what your desired results are to be in the area.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dave. The goal is to write a script and repeat the process for other models as well. How long do you think it would take to write a script like this?

Comment: Hard to say exactly for me as I don't know that it has or hasn't been done before and far from a master programmer. With some knowledge, research and lots of attempts a willing body could be testing in a month or 2, or more depending on time available/applied. Could be much longer too even for  the experienced depending on testing, compatibility, glitches etc. etc.